# Extract XML blocks as string in Java

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML as below

```
<accountProducts>
 <accountProduct>...</accountProduct>
 <accountProduct>...</accountProduct>
 <accountProduct>...</accountProduct>
 <accountProduct>...</accountProduct>
</accountProducts>
```

Now I want to extract each of the accountProduct block as string. So is there any XML parsing technique to do that or I need to do string manipulation.

Any help please.

Comment: Look into a [DOM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/)

Comment: Use XPath for querying XML

Comment: This sounds to me like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243567) - what is the higher-level goal here?  What do you need to do with the "strings" you extract?  If they're only going to get parsed again by a downstream component, maybe there's another approach you could use that would avoid the need to parse everything twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the DOM as suggested above, you will need to parse your XML with a DocumentBuilder.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
//if your document has namespaces, you can specify that in your builder.
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

Using this object, you can call the parse() method.
```

Your XML input can be provided to a DOM parser as a file or as a stream.

As a file...

```
File f = new File("MyXmlFile.xml");
Document d = db.parse(f);
```

As a string...

```
String myXmlString = "...";
InputSource ss = new InputSource(new StringReader(myXmlString));
Document d = db.parse(ss);
```

Once you have a Document object, you can traverse the document with DOM functions or with XPATH.  This example illustrates the DOM methods.

In your example, assuming that accountProduct nodes contain only text, the following should work.

```
NodeList nl = d.getElementsByTagName("accountProduct");
for(int i=0; i<nl.getLength(); i++) {
    Element elem = (Element)nl.item(i);
    System.out.println(elem.getTextContent());
}
```

If accountProduct contains mixed content (text and elements), you would need more code to extract what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JAXP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/) for this.

> The Java API for XML Processing (JAXP) is for processing XML data using applications written in the Java programming language.