# How can I parse in Java an xml block to string

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I've an xml like which looks like this one:

```
<rootElement>
 <title> randmonString </title>
 <subElement1> 
    <someInfo> info </someInfo>
    <subElemntTrash> trash </subElementTrash>
    <someInfo1> info1 </someInfo1>
 </subElement1>
 <trash>
  <subtrash> trash </subtrash>
 </trash>
 <date> 19.03.15 </date>
</rootElement>
```

I need to extract only `title`, some `/subElement1/subInfo`, `/subElement1/subInfo1` and `date`, rest should be automatically stored somewhere but without those elements, that were already extracted. I also should have possibility to marshal it back to the original xml.
It would be great if it can be done using annotation mapping.

Can someone give me the right direction to search?

Comment: This may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938425/extract-xml-blocks-as-string-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking about parsing, but then you want data extraction, data transformation and finally storing in some undefined form. Very broad question with many possible aporaches.

You can parse XML in java using DOM, SAX, StAX.

You can use XPath to extract interesting information, but it will not divide your document into the interesting bit and the 'rest'.

You can define XSLT templates, to initiate java Transformer, in order to split your input document into the interesting and 'the rest' parts.

You can use JAXB to map the xml into an java model (using your favourite the annotation mapping), and then you can build another representations containing your interesting and 'the rest' part. Then you can save both representation to different xml.